# mongoose not with variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I used `$not` command like this:

```
var nickname = 'jony';     
Chat.find({
  $or: [
    { 'nick': socket.nickname },
    { 'to': socket.nickname }
  ],
  dem: { $not: /"'+nickname+'"/ }
  },
  function (err, docs) {});
```

When I used like shown below it worked, but when I tried to put a variable like shown above 
it doesn't work.

```
dem : { $not: /jony/ }
```

How to put a variable in the `$not` operation above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoJS not returning data when searching with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597205/mongojs-not-returning-data-when-searching-with-regular-expressions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Comment: JavaScript's regular expression literals, like `/jony/`, don't currently support concatenation or interpolation, as you might find in other languages. You'll have to construct a `RegExp` providing the pattern as a `String` argument -- `{ $not: new RegExp(nickname) }`.